# How to make chrome dev-tools see custom object properties

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, typescript

I'm using a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) in a typescript class to intercept and dispatch on `get` and `set` operations. This is working great, and I've managed to get auto-completion working in vscode on these properties. However, when I use the chrome dev tools, the properties I'm handling with the `Proxy` do not autocomplete in the js console, nor do they show up in the 'intellisense' list that pops up when you type the `.`

I'm handling `ownKeys` in the `proxy` but this doesn't seem to help. This is when I realized that I have no idea how the chrome dev-tools implement the auto-completion.

Is there some other method I need to implement to make my properties show up as auto-completion candidates in the dev tools? I know that if I implemented them all as actual `get`/`set` pairs they show up but this is not a feasible option for reasons that are beyond the scope of the question.

Assuming I need to use a `Proxy` to implement `get`/`set` for some properties, is there a way to get them to show up in the chrome dev tools js console as auto-completions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around with it a bit and figured out that the Chrome Dev-Tools are pulling the properties from the object you're wrapping with the Proxy.

For instance

```js
test = new Proxy(
    {
        'alpha': null,
        'beta': null,
        'gamma': null
    },
    { 
        get: (target, prop, receiver) => {
            return prop;
        }
    }
)
```

Will display the properties.

[image: Chrome DevTools Proxy Autocomplete]

If the Typescript object you're wrapping with the Proxy has the properties on it. It's possible that typescript is removing them when compiling.

Comment: Oh, derp. I declared them in typescript (which is enough to get intellisense in vscode) but not ever initializing them--since I was using the proxy to dispatch on the names to another object in the class. Initializing all the proxied fields to null was sufficient to make auto-completion  work in chrome.